# How to join objects together for appending without messing up material settings

Tags: materials, objects, shaders, append

I need to append this eevee clay-like clock object I made into another blender project.
[image]

To do that easily I need to join all the objects together, but when I do, the clay material's scaling and preferences get messed up.

[image]

Is there any way to join it all into one object without messing up the material?

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, maybe others will have an idea, but have you tried moving all the objects into a collection without joining, and then appending that collection to another blend file?

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Did you Apply all scales before joining?